# random selection of numbers with known log-norm distibution

Tags: statistics

I have some (unknown) numbers that follow a log-norm distribution. What I know is that the mean value is 3 and the coefficient of variation of 0.5.
This means the range of St.dev. varies an order of magnitude.

How can in python generate 100 random variables from the mean and coefficient (in pyhton)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From desired mean `mu_d` and coefficient of variation `coeff_var`,

1. `var_d = mu_d * coeff_var`
2. Solve these expressions [3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) for `mu_x` and `var_x`.

[image: mean of lognormal]

[image: variance of lognormal]

3. With a given mean 'mu_x' and variance 'var_x' for underlying normal distribution. [4](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.lognormal.html)

```py
import numpy as np

# Mean and variance of underlying normal distribution
mu_x = 0
var_x = 1
sigma_x = np.sqrt(var_x)

# Samples from the distribution
s = np.random.lognormal(mu_x, sigma_x, 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.lognormal.html

```
import numpy as np

mean = 3  # mean
var_coef = 0.5  # coefficient of variation
std = var_coef * mean / 100  # standard deviation
s = np.random.lognormal(mean, std, 100)
print(s)
```

Comment: This is close, but not quite, right? The parameters for `np.random.lognormal` are the mean and s.d. for "the underlying normal distribution", it says in the documentation. The mean and s.d. for the lognormal are a function of those. Given the mean and s.d. for the lognormal, one would have to work backwards to get the parameters to supply to `np.random.lognormal`. Pretty sure the Wikipedia page for lognormal distribution has the formulas for mean and s.d.